Is there any way to adjust a "flatlining" pressure gauge on a pump?
At some point my cheapo Bontraeger floor bicycle pump was left outside, I would guess further that my kids submerged it and pumped it up and down for the LOLS. The pump seems to make ok pressure but the pressure gauge is completely flat at zero. I dissembled the pump completely and everything is relatively clean and in good functional form except for the pressure gauge. There is definitely a bit of water in the gauge component. On the preference of not being wasteful, is there any way to cheaply repair the pressure gauge or find a workaround for measuring pressure at the pump?

Have you disassembled, cleaned and lubricated inside the gauge?   Is this pump set up such that plugging the hole where the gauge threads in, will still allow the pump to function and inflate a tyre?
